# Unity Accessing Prefab From Code in Compile Time

Tags: unity-game-engine

My Scenario:

I have a child character that uses weapons one at a time. Let's say I have dozens of weapons. It would be cumbersome to assign these weapons in the Project Editor. (I prefer to do work from code as much as possible, because the Project Editor can be messed up sometimes). 
I know about the `Resources.Load` function, but it accesses the prefab at runtime. This is less performant than assigning in the editor, especially if the character switches weapons often.  
Is there a way to access prefabs from code that has the benefits from both options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There would be multiple ways to do this but I would create a folder inside of a folder called "Resources". Lets just say we call it "Weapons". You can then load all of the files in that folder once when the scene loads and keep them in an array like this:

`GameObject[] weapons = Resources.LoadAll<GameObject>("Weapons");`

The advantage here is that you only load the assets once so you don't have to load them during gameplay.

However, it shouldn't actually be cumbersome to manually assign the assets in the editor since you can just shift click to select all of them and drag them into the array.

Comment: This is still dynamic way, although not a bad solution.
It is Cumbersome because the project editor is harder to version control in case I accidently delete something from a prefab. Also I experiences some incosistencies when I exit unity and then reopen.